# Where do I find metatype qualities?

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun-sr5

I'm building a metahuman character using the Shadowrun 5E core rulebook. Both the core rulebook and the demo kit mention metahuman qualities (for example, the Elves' low-light vision). Where can I find these in the core book?

I've tried reading through the intuitive sections (character building, especially metatypes) and using the index - but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are listed in the table on page 66 for each metatype.

The rules are unfortunately scattered across the book. Sometimes a rule mentions such a quality and the effects.

Among the mentioned qualities are

- **increased lifestyle costs**: Pretty self-explanatory. You simply have to pay more to buy a lifestyle (p. 95).
- **Low-Light / Thermographic Vision**: The combat chapter mentions environmental modifiers including visibility. These quality's reduce those modifiers as described on p. 173 f. (or condensed in the *Environmental Compensation* table on p. 175)
- **dice bonus to resist toxins/pathogens**: Pretty self-explanatory, but for more on Toxins take a look at p. 408 f.; There are extended rules for diseases in *Run Faster*, p. 142
- **increased Reach**: Just add this to the reach of a melee weapon (effects described on p. 189 *Attacker/Defender has longer reach*)
- **Dermal armor**: Just provide a bonus to armor without encumberance (p. 169); Not comulative with Orthoskin/Dermal Plating as mentioned *somewhere*

There are several other qualities ones added for metagenetic variants (*Run Faster*). The descriptions for those can be found among the metagenetic qualities (RF, p. 111 ff.). Some qualities of infected can be found among the critter powers (core rulebook, p. 394 ff.).